# how to add Intuit.QuickBase.Core.Payload package to visual studio code

Tags: c#, api, quickbase

I am new to c# development and with quickbase, I would like to add this **Intuit.QuickBase.Core.Payload** package as reference in visual studio code and when i try to search the package with **Command Palette** it is not available. how to add such ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# guy, but I do know that the SDK you are referring to is available on GitHub and it's based on older SOAP/XML APIs from Quick Base.

Quick Base has a new RESTful/JSON API that might be easier to work: https://developer.quickbase.com/